# Resharper - not able to configure individual keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am a long time CodeRush user trying out Resharper 9 with VS 2013. I am not able to find the option for configuring individual keyboard shortcuts. I don't see list of commands under Environment > Keyboard & Menus as mentioned in the documentation. 'Apply Scheme' keeps the screen unchanged. What am I missing here?

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp60/Configuring_ReSharper__Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure ReSharper's keyboard shortcuts just like Visual Studio's - in Visual Studio's own keyboard dialog - Tools → Options → Keyboard. All ReSharper commands begin with "ReSharper" if you want to filter them.

Comment: Never though they merged it with the VS shortcuts! Their documentation is out dated. Thank you!